# How to get an index of a Pod of a Replication Controller?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Replication Controller whose size is more than one, and I'd like to embed the application monitoring profiler in only a pod in the replication controller. So I want the index or something to determine the pod is chosen only one. Especially in the GKE environment, is there such information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pods started by a replication controller are all treated identically; they don't have any sort of ordinality.

If you want to start a group of identical pods and enable an extra feature in just one of them, you should consider using a master election scheme and having just the elected master run the monitoring profiler.

Comment: Just an idea, can I utilize etcd from the container? If so, I'd implement a lock on etcd.

Comment: The etcd instance that is used by the master for storage isn't directly accessible from nodes in a GKE cluster. You can, however, run your own etcd instance ([like we do for the dns cluster add-on](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a3c00aadd5da91288cca856dabbefbc9f261be69/cluster/addons/dns/skydns-rc.yaml.in#L23-L48)) and use that for master election.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You will be interested in the parametrized set/templating proposal that will allow you to define indices  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/docs/proposals/templates.md. This will most likely be included in 1.3.